# Why does this code not clear mouse events from the SDL Events Poll?

Tags: mouseevent, sdl, sdl-2

I found some of this code from other StackOverflow questions, but basically in my code I run an SDL_Delay and I don't want any mouse events to be registered during this delay, but they still are so I run this code:

```
SDL_FlushEvents(SDL_USEREVENT, SDL_LASTEVENT);
SDL_PollEvent( &event );
event.type = SDL_USEREVENT;
event.button.x = 0;
event.button.y = 0;
```

But even after this code after the next SDL_PollEvent(&event), the mouse up events are registered. How do I fix this and stop these mouse events from being registered?

Comment: [SDL_FlushEvents](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_FlushEvents) documentation states "This function only affects currently queued events. If you want to make sure that all pending OS events are flushed, you can call SDL_PumpEvents() on the main thread immediately before the flush call."

Comment: @keltar I tried adding SDL_PumpEvents() before the flush call and it still doesn't work.

Comment: You only clear user event types of events (between `SDL_USEREVENT` and `SDL_LASTEVENT`). Mouse event type is lower so it isn't cleared. You can clear everything with `SDL_FlushEvents(SDL_FIRSTEVENT, SDL_LASTEVENT)`.

Comment: @keltar that was it, thanks for the help, can you put that in answer form so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SDL_FlushEvents](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_FlushEvents) only clears events that are currently in the SDL queue. Events are put into queue by `SDL_PumpEvents` call (called internally by `SDL_PollEvent`). In addition, in clears events in specified type range. As written in question, it clears only events of type "user event" (every type with value higher than SDL_USEREVENT is available as user event type). To clear all events, you want to clear types [0, MAX], or special aliases `SDL_FIRSTEVENT` (0) and `SDL_LASTEVENT` (maximum value event type can take).

To sum it up:

```
SDL_PumpEvents();
SDL_FlushEvents(SDL_FIRSTEVENT, SDL_LASTEVENT);
```

If required, you can check actual values of event types in `SDL_event.h` file. If you only want to clear mouse events, it would be e.g. `SDL_FlushEvents(SDL_MOUSEMOTION, SDL_MOUSEMOTION+0x50)`.

The other way to do the same is to process entire event queue until it is empty - e.g.

```
while(SDL_PollEvent(NULL)) {}
```